# Selenium page load strategy to not wait for initial load

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

According to the docs, the options for the load strategy are normal, eager, and none. none seems to be the one with the least blocking time for the driver but it still waits for an initial load of the page before I can go to a different url. I would like to at some point during the script, click on a link that goes somewhere, and while it is still initially loading go to a different url. Is there a way to get the driver to not get blocked during that time or even a workaround?

Answer (score 3):

This is how to properly set the `page_load_strategy` to `"none"` with Python Selenium:

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service

service = Service()
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.page_load_strategy = "none"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=service, options=options)
# ...
driver.quit()
```

Note that you need to use `"none"`, NOT `None`, which is a common mistake.

Options are `"none"`, `"eager"`, and `"normal"`.

Comment: I understand this but this is not my question, I am using using a `page_load_strategy` of `none` but it still blocks the driver until the initial load, I want to bypass this block and immediately be able to go to another URL even though the current one has not initially loaded.

Comment: With `selenium` there will always be some initial load, but you can skip loading page resources. In what scenario are you trying to load nothing at all, but still hit a page?

Comment: Well the exact scenario is I need to press a button, then after about 1.5 seconds after go to a different link. But the initial loading of the page that the button accesses takes about 4-5 seconds and even setting the strategy to none waits those full 4-5 seconds until the initial load so I would like a guaranteed way to be able to go to a different url during that wait time.

Comment: A possible workaround is to load your page in an iframe, and then click from there. Eg. https://seleniumbase.io/w3schools/sbase - Standard selenium waiting rules won't apply.